# Printing map value by assigning into string variable

Tags: java

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
String prevObject=map.put(1, "JavaGoal");
System.out.println(prevObject);
```

The solution is null here. But I don't know why it comes as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

The above line of code creates an instance of class `HashMap` that contains no entries. In other words, the `HashMap` is empty.

```java
String prevObject = map.put(1, "JavaGoal");
```

The above line of code adds a single entry to the `HashMap`. The `HashMap` now contains exactly one entry. The entry contains a key and a value. The key is the integer `1` and the value is the string `JavaGoal`.

Method `put` also returns the previous value of the entry whose key was the integer `1`. But before calling method `put` there was **no** entry in the `HashMap` with that key. In fact there were no entries. Hence there was no previous value. Hence the method `put` returned null.

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) for the return value of `put`

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.(A null return can also indicate that the mappreviously associated null with key.)

i.e. there is no pre-existing value for that key. Typically `get` is used to retrieve the current value

```
 System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

Comment: I think you're confusing the current value with the previous value...there is no previous value. Add in another value with this key and you'll get `JavaGoal`